# Can a trigger be locked; how would one determine that it is?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

In answering [Will I miss any changes if I replace an oracle trigger while my application is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18454052/458741), I went looking to see if the trigger was locked by an INSERT statement. It wasn't and I can't find anything on the internet to suggest that a trigger can be locked.

If I run the following in one session:

```
create table test_trigger (id number);
create table test_trigger_h (id number);

create or replace trigger test_trigger_t 
 after insert on test_trigger for each row
begin
  insert into test_trigger_h (id) values (:new.id);
end;    
/

insert into test_trigger
 select level
   from dual
connect by level <= 1000000;
```

and then in a second session try to find out what locks are occurring I get the following:

```
select object_name, object_type
     , case l.block
            when 0 then 'Not Blocking'
            when 1 then 'Blocking'
            when 2 then 'Global'
       end as status
     , case v.locked_mode
            when 0 then 'None'
            when 1 then 'Null'
            when 2 then 'Row-S (SS)'
            when 3 then 'Row-X (SX)'
            when 4 then 'Share'
            when 5 then 'S/Row-X (SSX)'
            when 6 then 'Exclusive'
            else to_char(lmode)
       end as mode_held
  from v$locked_object v
  join dba_objects d
    on v.object_id = d.object_id
  join v$lock l
    on v.object_id = l.id1
  join v$session s
    on v.session_id = s.sid
       ;

OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYPE          STATUS          MODE_HELD
-------------------- -------------------- --------------- ---------------
TEST_TRIGGER         TABLE                Not Blocking    Row-X (SX)
TEST_TRIGGER_H       TABLE                Not Blocking    Row-X (SX)
```

According to Oracle, the trigger is *not* being locked.

However, if I try to replace the trigger whilst the INSERT statement is running it will not be replaced until after the statement has completed (not including a commit), which implies that the trigger *is* locked.

In this situation, is the trigger locked and if so how would one determine that it is?

Comment: Similar, you are unable to recompile a package/function/procedure while a session is executing it. It is not a classic "data" lock, but a "library cache" lock.

Comment: It think it is a `TM` lock. This one is held by any statement and prevent any DDL on depending objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To determine if a trigger(as well as any other stored procedure) is locked or not, the [V$ACCESS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_1003.htm) dynamic performance view can be queried.

```
Session #1

insert into test_trigger
 select level
   from dual
connect by level <= 1000000; 

Session #2

SQL> select *
  2    from v$access
  3   where object = upper('test_trigger_t')
  4  ;


Sid  Owner  Object         Type    Con_Id 
--------------------------------------
441  HR     TEST_TRIGGER_T TRIGGER  3
```

Those kinds of *locks* are library cache pins(library cache locks are resource(`TM` type of lock) locks), needed to ensure that an object is protected from being modified while session is executing it.

```
--session sid # 441
insert into test_trigger
  select level
    from dual
 connect by level <= 1000000;


-- session sid #24
create or replace trigger test_trigger_t 
after insert on test_trigger for each row
begin
  insert into test_trigger_h (id) values (:new.id);
end;  

-- Session # 3
select vs.sid
     , vs.username
     , vw.event
  from v$session       vs
  join v$session_wait  vw
    on (vw.sid = vs.sid)
  join v$access        va
    on (va.owner = vs.username)
 where vs.username = 'HR'
```

Result:

```
Sid Username Event 
--------------------------
24 HR library cache pin 
....
441 HR log file switch (checkpoint incomplete)
```

Here we can see that the session #441 waits for a log file switching and session #24 waits for library cache pin.