# Drop Command for particular stored procedure failing

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

The drop procedure command is running but not finishing or raising an error.

How can I check if the stored procedure is being used by another session, thus locking it?

Comment: Provide stored procedure code snippet, so that others could help to find the problem.

Comment: The code is not having any error , and i cant share it here , i just want to know , is there any technique to check the instance which are using this stored procedre.

Comment: If you are using TOAD, there is a `Used By` tab, which gives you list of other objects which uses stored procedure.

Comment: This sounds similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18460260/266304); not sure it's exactly a duplicate but the answer there might show what's using your procedure and preventing it being dropped. Of course, if it's being used, maybe you shouldn't be dropping it...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query to find out referenced database objects

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  all_dependencies
 WHERE  referenced_name ='<objectname>'
```

Comment: Dependencies don't stop a procedure being dropped.